# Comparing two ISO8601 dates strings in PHP

Tags: php

I need to compare (actually rank/sort) dates in a PHP script. The dates are ISO-8601 Date format i.e.

**YYYY-MM-DD**

I wrote a comparison function which splits the dates and compares by year/month/day. However, it seems this may be overkill and I could just as easily done a simple string comparison like:

```
if ($date1 < $date2)
   // do something
elseif( $date1 > $date2)
   //do something else
else
   //do yet another thing
```

Is my assumption about (ISO-8601) Date string comparison correct - i.e. can I get rid of my function (to save a few clock cycles on the server), or is it safer to explicity do the comparison in a custom function?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#General_principles

> Date and time values are organized from the most to the least significant: year, month (or week), day, hour, minute, second, and fraction of second. The lexicographical order of the representation thus corresponds to chronological order, except for date representations involving negative years. This allows dates to be naturally sorted by, for example, file systems.

Go ahead with string sorting. If wikipedia is not enough, then surely http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt is, search for strcmp in there.

Comment: +1 RFC reference, although you should perhaps also have listed the caveats. *"Assuming that the time
   zones of the dates and times are the same (e.g., all in UTC),
   expressed using the same string (e.g., all "Z" or all "+00:00"), and
   all times have the same number of fractional second digits, then the
   date and time strings may be sorted as strings (e.g., using the
   strcmp() function in C)"*

Answer (score 8):

If you turn your dates into [`DateTime` objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) (Usually available from PHP 5.2+), you can reliably use comparisons regardless of format.

```
$date = new DateTime("YYYY-MM-DD");
$date2 = new DateTime("YYYY-MM-DD");

if ($date > $date2)  .....
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have two dates in ISO 8601 format then, yes, you can compare them as strings. And this solution have best performance:

```
Test name       Repeats         Result          Performance     
string          10000           0.031393 sec    +0.00%
strcmp          10000           0.040579 sec    -29.26%
strtotime       10000           0.149791 sec    -377.15%
DateTime        10000           0.184489 sec    -487.68%
```

Test source [here](https://github.com/nafigator/php-bench/blob/master/Tests/CompareISO8601Dates.php).

Answer (score 2):

If you have at least PHP 5.2, I would recommend [Pekka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098205/comparing-two-iso8601-dates-strings-in-php/5098239#5098239). If that's not an option, you can convert the date to a number and compare it numerically:

```
if(strtotime('YYYY-MM-DD') > strtotime('YYYY-MM-DD'))
{
   // code
}
```

Edit:

As Maerlyn pointed out in the comments, the Unix epoch has a limited range. If you are guaranteed to have zeros in front of the 1-digit months and dates, you could also use [`strcmp`](http://php.net/strcmp):

```
if(strcmp('2011-05-04', '2011-04-05') > 0)
{
   // First date is larger
}
```

Comment: You just need to keep in mind the range of unix timestamps (1970-2038).

Comment: I don't think comparing with strcmp actually works. We had some flaws with it. I would rather rely on comparing real dates or milliseconds then hoping about some string magic.