# dynamodb filter based on LocalDate in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have DynamoDB Table structure as follows.

| Attribute Name | finalDate | originDate | submittedBy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Data Type | Java.util.Date | Java.time.LocalDate | Java.lang.String |

I need to fetch all records from the table as follows:

select * from TableName where originDate > certainDate

And, **originDate is the partition key**.

How should I approach this problem?
Do I need to load all the data and filter the results using java programming in API?

or can I directly fetch all the records with above condition. Any Suggestions ??

Comment: You cannot use DynamoDB `Query` here as you are not searching by a partition key and hence you have to use `Scan`. AFAIK, scan supports a filter expression but that is applied after the scan. Hence, the net effect is you will be reading all the items anyway (in terms of the RCU). Another concern is dynamoDB does not support Date data type - it is only stored as a String - so I doubt you will be able to apply comparison operators on that field.

Comment: Ref - [Working with Queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html), [Working with Scans](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html)

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30713517/4405757) clarifies that date comparison would work as they are stored in ISO-8601 format.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding...

Unlike Query, a Scan does not support a key Condition expression. It supports [Filter Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.FilterExpression) so you don't need to read all items and filter in your application.

But.. note the below statement from the documentation,

> A filter expression is applied after a Scan finishes but before the results are returned. Therefore, a Scan consumes the same amount of read capacity, regardless of whether a filter expression is present.

Hence, regarding the cost, you will have to pay for the RCU for reading the entire table.

Note: A scan returns max 1MB of data. So make sure to use the pagination to read the full result set.

Reference

- [Working with Queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html)
- [Working with Scans](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html)